# Get a list of files in an online directory

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to get a list of the latest weather radar image files from: http://radar.weather.gov/ridge/Conus/RadarImg/

Then I need to download the latest 5 images with the format "Conus_YYYYMMDD_HHMM_N0Ronly.gif"

I'm stuck in the first step, which is to get the list of the files in that directory.

I've tried:

```
NSString *path = @"http://radar.weather.gov/ridge/Conus/RadarImg/";
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *dirFiles = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:path error:&error];
    NSLog(@"error: %@",error);
    return dirFiles;
```

But I get an error 260 "The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory, NSFilePath=radar.weather.gov/ridge/Conus/RadarImg/"

Is this the wrong way to download a directory listing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is the wrong way, because there **is** no way of downloading a directory listing over HTTP*.

Remember that HTTP has no concept of listing a directory — what you are looking at on that web page is an HTML document that happens to contain a listing of the directory. You will need to parse the text of that document and extract the URLs from it.

*: Other than by using DAV, but that isn't an option here, or in most cases.